# Mysql error (#1064) You have an error in your SQL syntaxfor the right syntax to use near '' at line 20

Tags: mysql, syntax, phpmyadmin

I can't figure out what mistake I did.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ajoutEmprunt(nss FLOAT(15, 0), codeB INT(14), dateEm DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE nbMaxBook INT;
DECLARE nbCurrentBook INT;
DECLARE late INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nbCurrentBook FROM emprunte WHERE emprunte.nssU = nss GROUP BY emprunte.nssU; 

    SELECT categorie.nbMaxOuv 
    INTO nbMaxBook
    FROM categorie, appartient_a, utilisateur 
    WHERE categorie.idCat = appartient_a.idCat AND appartient_a.nssU=utilisateur.nssU;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emprunte WHERE nss = emprunte.nssU GROUP BY emprunte.nssU HAVING DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, emprunte.dateLimite) < 0))
            THEN SET late = 1;
    ELSE IF nbCurrentBook = 0 THEN SET late = 0;
    END IF;

    IF nbCurrentBook < nbMaxBook AND late = 0
            THEN INSERT INTO emprunte(nssU, codeBarre, dateEmprunt) VALUES(nss,codeB, dateEm);
    END IF;
END|
```

Actually I know that the problem is raised by this block of code :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emprunte WHERE nss = emprunte.nssU GROUP BY emprunte.nssU HAVING DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, emprunte.dateLimite) < 0)
        THEN SET retard = 1;
```

But I don't know how to fix it or replace it.
If you have any idea, it would be welcomed !

Comment: This *usually* relates to a mismatch in parentheses, so I'd start there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a `)` too much and it is `ELSEIF` and not `ELSE IF`

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emprunte WHERE nss = emprunte.nssU GROUP BY emprunte.nssU HAVING DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, emprunte.dateLimite) < 0)
     THEN SET late = 1;
ELSEIF nbCurrentBook = 0 
     THEN SET late = 0;
END IF;
```

You should check out a SQL tool like *MySQL Workbench* which highlights errors and makes it way easier fixing them.